# Scraping Justdial

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from Justdial for school name , address and phone number. I have the script ready. I am using Scrappy and selenium. However I am getting a HTTP error 403(forbidden) and 504(gateway timeout) from Justdial server. It says access denied. For any other website when I use scrappy using fetch we are able to get the source code but for Justdial it shows access denied.

```
import scrapy

class JustSpider(scrapy.Spider) :
name = 'school'
start_urls = [
    'https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/search?q=Schools'
]

def parse(self, response) :
    title = response.css('title::text').extract()
    yield {'titletext': title}
```

I have used several User Agent types and tried it on different machines with different networks, used VPNs, proxies to run this program. Even if I try to extract even a simple line of text from Justdial I get the same error.

First I get 403 error and then after some attempts I get 504 error like this:-

Ignoring response <504 [https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/search?q=Schools>](https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/search?q=Schools%3E): HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

and after this the spider closes.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I added `USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0'` to the `settings.py` file to get it working.